# Link bigger than image

Tags: css

I looked around the boards a bit and couldn't find anything that worked for me, but basically when I center an image that has an anchor tag wrapped around it, the linkable area fills out to fit the entire width of the div, even when specifying a width. How can I get the link to only be around the image?

Link to JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jJ4hv/

HTML

```
        <div id="right">

        <div id="content">

            <div class="title">
                <h3>Spawn</h3>
                <a href="index.html"><p>&lt;&lt; Go Back</p></a>
            </div>

            <a href="images/spawn.png" data-lightbox="inks" title="Spawn"><img src="images/spawnThumb.png" /></a>
            <p class="description">Spawn</p>

        </div><!-- END content -->

    </div><!-- END right -->
```

CSS

```
    #content img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}

.title {
    border-bottom: thin solid #316b9c;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.title a {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #bcbdbf;
}

.title a:hover {
    color: #316b9c;
}

.title a:active {
    color: #000;
}

.topImage {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
    color: #bcbdbf;
}
```

Comment: In addition to your source, please include a link to a JSfiddle or something that has an example recreated in it.

Comment: Why so many down votes with no explanation as to why?

Comment: Thanks for updating with the JSfiddle. I not only removed my downvote but voted it up because the question is now very demonstrative. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add #content a to the #content img CSS.

```
#content img,
#content a{
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jJ4hv/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly apply

```
display: table;
margin: auto
```

to the [a] tag surrounding the image.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue by adding text-align: center to the a tag!

```
#content a {
     text-align: center;
}
```